# Angularjs: Unable to access individual elements in $routeParams but can access it as a whole

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am having a bizarre problem accessing values in $routeParams in angularjs.

I set up routing in my app as

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl : './templates/main.html',
        }).when('/:year/:month/:day',{
            templateUrl : './templates/day.html',
        }).otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Basically, if there are 3 routeparams, then they're assigned to `year`, `month`, and `day`.

My body looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="calController">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Now, in calController, I want to access the routeparams;

If I do

```
console.log($routeParams);
```

in calController, it successfully prints out the parameters in what seems to be json format. However, if I try

```
console.log($routeParams["year"]);
console.log($routeParams.year);
```

both of these statements print out undefined. What's going on? How do I access the year parameter in the controller?

Edit: as requested, here's calController:

```
app.controller('calController', function calController($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
    console.log($routeParams["year"]);
    console.log($routeParams.year);
}
```

Comment: Did you inject the $routeParams dependency in your controller ?  can you please share the code of calController ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have `calController` outside of `ng-view`. This means that the controller will run before `ui.router` has had time to initialize.

Also note that `console.log($routeParams);`, initially, displays an empty object `{}` which gets populated once the params are ready. This happens after a couple of milliseconds. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify($routeParams));` and you'll convince yourself that the objects is empty.

This explains the *"weird"* behavior you have encountered.